# Get row with NaN as well as preceding and following NaN row

Tags: pandas, nan

I have the following snippet from an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['Seattle', np.nan, 'Portland', 'San Francisco'],
                   'time': ['2022-06-01 12:00:00', '2022-06-01 13:00:00', '2022-06-01 14:00:00', '2022-06-01 15:00:00']})
```

I would like to retrieve the rows where location = nan as well as the non-nan row above and below.

So that it will be as such

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['Seattle', np.nan, 'Portland'], 'time': ['2022-06-01 12:00:00', '2022-06-01 13:00:00', '2022-06-01 14:00:00']})
```

How can I achieve this? The dataframe is larger than the example snippet with different cases. But generally is should be: Retrieve all rows with NaN plus the next non-nan row above or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chain mass by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m = df['location'].isna()

df = df[m.shift(fill_value=False) | m.shift(-1, fill_value=False) | m]
print (df)
   location                 time
0   Seattle  2022-06-01 12:00:00
1       NaN  2022-06-01 13:00:00
2  Portland  2022-06-01 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a centered [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to generate the mask for [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 1
m = (df['location'].isna()
      .rolling(2*N+1, min_periods=1, center=True)
      .max().eq(1)
     )

out = df.loc[m]
```

*You can easily generalize to any number of rows before/after by changing `N`.*

Output:

```
   location                 time
0   Seattle  2022-06-01 12:00:00
1       NaN  2022-06-01 13:00:00
2  Portland  2022-06-01 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `ffill()` and `bfill()`

```
n = 1
s = df['location'].isna()
df.loc[s.where(s).ffill(limit=n).bfill(limit=n).fillna(False)]
```

Output:

```
   location                 time
0   Seattle  2022-06-01 12:00:00
1       NaN  2022-06-01 13:00:00
2  Portland  2022-06-01 14:00:00
```